# When I reset my theme in WordPress and upload it again, it is not default

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, elementor, custom-wordpress-pages

I have bought the Pylon theme and I tried to reset it with plugins, but when I try to upload and activate it again, nothing has changed. The theme does not have the default appearance and settings.

I tried to delete the theme, upload it again.

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "I tried to reset it with plugins", but your theme's settings are probably stored in database like most of the time, so deleting the theme files won't have any effect.

You'd better ask the theme developer if there's any way to restore the default settings (sometimes there's an option for that).

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: My account has been upgraded to the business plan and I have bought a theme, the Pylon theme. I uploaded it but then some errors occurred and I wanted to reset it because I cannot make the changes I want to do. I downloaded a "restore" plugin and I restored the theme and everything else. everything was deleted, the plugins, media, posts, etc. Now, I want to reupload this theme and I need it to the previews state, as it was when I bought it.